# How to take column backup for a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How to take column backup for a table in mysql.we have any command for it.Please provide the solution for it

Comment: You may want to take a look at:  
journalling
and/or  
triggers

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, it is not a free code writing service, so statements such as "Please provide the solution for it" are unlikely to incite helpful answers. Demonstrate some effort on your part and others are more likely to put the effort in to helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySqlBackup.NET to help to do that:
http://mysqlbackupnet.codeplex.com

```
string file = "C:\\backup.sql";
string conn = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";
var mb = new MySqlBackup(conn);
mb.ExportInfo.FileName = file;
mb.ExportRows = false;
mb.ExportTableStructure = true;
mb.Export();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can export only selected fields through **"mysql"** command line utility

See below example:

```
mysql -u USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --database=DATABASE --execute='SELECT `FIELD`, `FIELD` FROM `TABLE` LIMIT 0, 10000 ' -X > file.xml
```

Comment: hello minesh,how to import this file .other than using load data command.

Comment: @mithunakous mysql -u USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --database=DATABASE < file.sql

Comment: i am getting below error while importing                                       [root@ravitestserver ~]# mysql -u root --password=xxx --database=prep<file_colm.sql
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<?xml version="1.0"?>

<resultset statement="SELECT `name`, `species` FROM `pet`' at line 1

Comment: Please check from where the below data is coming :

<?xml version="1.0"?> <resultset statement